# Google Code svn migration

Tags: svn, migration, google-code

How to migrate from Google Code's subversion to another subversion server keeping the history?
The problem here is that I don't have access to the repository of Google Code, nor to the one I will migrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can 'svnsync' the data from Google code to a local repository on your pc. You can then use 'svnadmin' to create a dump file from that and send that to your new hosting provider or in some cases you can use svnsync to upload to the repository.

The only public hosting I know that supports svnsync upload is Google code (it requires clearing the repository first), which most likely doesn't help you, but there might be others now.

Answer (score 2):

The [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync) command might be what you need. It allows you to create a copy of an existing repository to which you do not have file level access.