# Migrate code from svn to google code

Tags: svn, google-code

I know we could migrate repository from google to another repository sever and keep the history, like described here. [Google Code svn migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846050/google-code-svn-migration)

I am wondering if I can do the other way around. I have some code in a private svn repository, and I would like to move them to google code without losing history. Can I import, say, an svn dump image to google-code site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure is documented here: http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_do_I_import_an_existing_Subversion_repository?

I suppose that covers it quite well :)